# ORACLE sql error - ORA-00933 - executing join operation - DBeaver

Tags: sql, oracle, join, table-alias

I'm trying to execute the next:

```
SELECT l.id AS id
FROM s.process AS l 
JOIN s.item AS r ON l.id = r.id;
```

But I'm getting:

```
Query execution failed
Reason:
SQL Error [933] [42000]: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Using:

- DBeaver
- ojdbc7.jar as driver

Comment: can you please share your both table name and column list

Comment: I've found the problem using the first answer here... `AS` isn't relevant for ORACLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove `AS` when defining alias of table/view:

```
SELECT l.id AS id
FROM s.process l 
JOIN s.item r ON l.id = r.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle supports table aliases but It supports AS in the SELECT list but not in the FROM list:

```
SELECT l.id AS id
FROM s.process l 
JOIN s.item r ON l.id = r.id;
```